# Error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

I was playing around with some code i found online.  It's in Python 2.  When i ran the code in Python 3, it gives me this error:  a byte-like object is required, not 'str'.  can someone help me fix this?  thank you very much

```
import urllib.request as ur 
text = 
 ur.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryanmcdermott/trump-
speeches/master/speeches.txt')  
words = []  
for line in text:  
    line = line.decode('utf-8-sig', errors='ignore')
    line = line.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    line = line.replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')
    new_words = line.split(' ')
    new_words = [word for word in new_words if word not in ['', ' ']]
    words = words + new_words

print('Corpus size: {0} words.'.format(len(words)))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just cast `line` into `str` and error will be gone

```
line = line.replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')
```

to

```
 line = str(line).replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')
```